# AngularJS - $resource with :id in the middle of url

Tags: angularjs

I need to get this resource inside a factory:

```
Content: $resource("http://localhost:3000/matches/:id/content")
```

But when I try to access it with:

```
Content.get({id: $scope.match.id}, function(){});
```

I got an error because it is trying to reach "/matches/content" instead "/matches/123/content" (supposing the id is 123).

```
GET http://localhost:3000/matches/content 404 (Not Found)
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is fine. The problem is that `$scope.match.id` resolves to `undefined` and which results into resource URL with omitted `:id` part (and duplicated `/` also removed).

To verify that resource is all right check

```
Content.get({id: 123}, function(){});
```

and also `console.log($scope.match.id)`.

Comment: What a shame... you are right dfsq. Undefined is the reason.

Answer (score 3):

Should work fine here is fiddle that tests it out.  Could you be calling it too early?

http://jsfiddle.net/mbkq12wu/1/

```
angular.module('userApp', ['ngResource'])
    .factory('Content', function($resource) {
        return $resource("http://localhost:3000/matches/:id/content");
});

describe('SO Content Test resource calls matches/1/content', function () {
    it('Calls GET – api/:id/content', function() {

      $httpBackend
         .expectGET('http://localhost:3000/matches/1/content').respond(200);

        Content.get({id: 1}, function(){});
        $httpBackend.flush();
});
```